# Is there any category whose objects are semigroup acts and morphisms are semilinear morphism between acts?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, group-actions, semigroups, functors

I know that for a particular semigroup S all the S-acts form a category with S-act homomorphisms. My question is what happens if we do not fix the semigroup i.e. taking all semigroup acts (S,A) where S and A both varies and semilinear morphisms (μ,f):(S,A)→(T,B) playing the role of morphisms berween objects can we have a category? If yes where can I get some access to read about them?

Comment: aka "semigroup actions."

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: What do you call exactly *semilinear morphisms* in this context?

Comment: By semilinear morphism (μ,f):(S,A)→(T,B) I mean a pair of mappings where μ:S→T is a semigroup homomorphism and f:A→B is a mapping such that f(sa)=μ(s)f(a) for all s∈S and a∈A.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$You can define a contravariant functor ${\rm Act} : {\bf Sgrp} \to {\bf Cat}$ sending a semigroup $S$ to the category ${\rm Act}(S)$ of $S$-acts (I'll let you find how it is defined on morphisms $u : A\to T$, sending a $T$-act $B$ to the $S$-act $u^*B$), and the [comma category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comma+category)

$$\begin{CD}
{\cal E} @>>> 1 \\ 
@VVV\Downarrow @VV{\bf 1}V\\
{\bf Sgrp} @>>{\rm Act}> {\bf Cat}
\end{CD}$$

is the category you are trying to define. (${\bf 1}$ picks the terminal category in $\bf Cat$). By definition of this comma category, $\cal E$ has

1. objects given by pairs $(S,A)$ where $A\in{\rm Act}(S)$;
2. morphisms $(S,A)\to (T,B)$ given by pairs $(u,f)$ where $u : S\to T$ is a semigroup homomorphism, and $f : A\to B$ is a function that is equivariant between the $S$-act $A$ and the $S$-act $u^*B$.

Unwinding this second condition, $f : A\to B$ is such that $f(s.a) = u(s).fa$ for every $a\in A$, $s\in S$.

Comment: I have understood how the contravariant functor is defined on morphisms u:S→T. But  I can't understand how you are defining the objects in the comma category ? I have read the article you provided but according to that the objects should be triples. Please can you explain in more detail the comma category construction you presented above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: An object in the comma category in question is a triple $(1,S,M)$ where $1$ is the terminal category, $S$ is an object of $\bf Sgrp$ and $M : 1 \to {\rm Act}(S)$ is a functor. So, it's an object $M$ of ${\rm Act}(S)$.